# Why is there no int overload for SqlFunctions.StringConvert

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities

Title pretty much sums it up.  I'd bet that over half the usage of this method in the wild involves someone casting an int to a decimal or double in order to use it, so why isn't there just an overload that takes an int as the argument?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert.aspx

Comment: Or `IConvertible` would be event better

Comment: @CloseVoter I'm pretty sure there's an actual reason its set up this way and this won't degenerate into subjective debate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's directly related to the STR function found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

and that function only takes a float, hence the parameters you're seeing.