# EF Code First - convert string to int in query

Tags: entity-framework, type-conversion, code-first

I need to convert String to Int32 value in my query. It must be done on sql server-side, not in memory.
I've seen answers how to do this in Model First approach, LINQ to Entities. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754218/convert-string-to-int-in-ef-4-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met/5971677#5971677)
But I need it to be done with Code First.

I write query to DbSet<>.

Is there any way to do this? Please, help :)

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**:
The only way I can find information for is to use a custom query.
For instance:

```
from user in Users.SqlQuery("SELECT Id, CAST(Age AS INT) as Age, FirstName, LastName FROM Users")
select new 
{
    id = user.Id,
    Age = user.Age
}
```

In my tests it seems every value for property on the entity you map to have to be included in the select even if you select to a custom object that do not include every property. In my example above I include FirstName and LastName even though they aren't used in the select.

**Old answer:**
About converting to string on sql-side:
You can use SqlFunctions.StringConvert if you cast your int to a double or decimal first
[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

```
from user in Users
select new
{
    IdAsText = SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)user.Id)
}
```

The cast to float or decimal is necessary because the STR-function on the sql-server requires a float: [Why is there no int overload for SqlFunctions.StringConvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806315/why-is-there-no-int-overload-for-sqlfunctions-stringconvert)

Update:

In LINQPad the generated SQL-query from the above comes out to:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
STR( CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS decimal(19,0))) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: Fredrik, what type does StringConvert() return? And what type I need.